# googlesheets getting cell value into an array

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

i'm trying to loop through a range and get the value then push the value into an array. However, it's not working. I tried using the debugger and it's stuck at the line where
ranking.push...... is. i've tried using both the while loop way and for each way but neither works. This is what the Execution Transcript says: "Execution failed: Cannot convert function mergeAcross() {/* */} 9 to (class)". 
Can anyone please help? Cheers.

```
for each (i in rankTable){
ranking.push(dashboard.getRange(2,i+9).getValue()); //this line is the problem
i++;              
}

while (dashboard.getRange(2,i+9).getValues() != '') {
ranking.push(dashboard.getRange(2,i+9).getValue()); //same problem here
i++;
}
```

Thanks guys!

Comment: Use getValues() to fetch value of multiple cell at once. Don't fetch and push one by one. That's not a good way.
Kindly check documentation of and use getLastRow() and getValues()

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using `.getValues()` returns a 2D Array, so you don't need to push *unless* you're grabbing a subset of the data. If you want the full range, it's easier to just get all the values at once. Each row is an array with comma-separated columns.

This is assuming a 2 column setup:

```js
function create2DArray() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  Logger.log(data)
  // [ [Row 1 Col 1, Row 1 Col 2], [Row 2 Col 1, Row 2 Col 2]... ]
}
```

If you want to push a subset (a specific column, let's say) to create a 1D array, do the following:

```js
function createNewArray() {
  var sheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSheet();
  var data = sheet.getDataRange().getValues();

  var array = [];

  for(var i=0; i<data.length; i++) {
    // Push only column 1
    array.push(data[i][0])

    // Or create a 2D array of rows
    // array.push([data[i][0]])
  }

  Logger.log(array)
  // [Row 1 Col 1, Row 2 Col 1, Row 3 Col 1...]
}
```

Comment: thanks Brian, I'm assuming that the opposite is also true. I can also assign value to a range at once too?

Comment: @Tanpo Yes, you can use `.setValue()` with a string or 1D array. `.setValues()` takes a 2D array and will write to a range.